# Vaadin 24 - Grid Inline Edit - Select Control Rather Than Editable Field?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a grid that has an edit button and cancel button - much like the documentation of the "Inline Editing" section of the grid control (https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/grid#inline-editing-java-only).

Everything is working just fine.

However, I want to show a select component for an integer field - with the select showing "Yes" or "No" and have the return value an integer or 1 or 0.

My code for the "plain" field editor (where they can type an integer) is:

```
// integer field
IntegerField txtIsAncillary = new IntegerField();
txtIsAncillary.setWidthFull();
binder.forField(txtIsAncillary).bind(SJRolesQA::getIsAncillary, SJRolesQA::setIsAncillary);
isAncillaryColumn.setEditorComponent(txtIsAncillary);
```

How can I show a select component that is linked to the integer field?

**UPDATE:**
I'm stuck on the converter - I think if I can get that - I'll be home free. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
Select<String> txtIsAncillary = new Select<>();
txtIsAncillary.setItems("Yes","No");
txtIsAncillary.setWidthFull();
binder.forField(txtIsAncillary)
     .withConverter(text -> text == "Yes" ? 1 : 0)
     .bind(SJRolesQA::getIsAncillary, SJRolesQA::setIsAncillary);
isAncillaryColumn.setEditorComponent(txtIsAncillary);
```

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid - but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using a converter in the binding?

Comment: Hey @cfrick - that's what I'm planning to do, but I don't know how to display a select component rather than a plain integer field.

Comment: Does replacing the IntegerField wiht https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/select not work?

Comment: The trick is in the converter. I'm working with https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/binding-data/components-binder-validation#converting-user-input and am trying to make it work. Thank you - you helped point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@cfrick to the rescue again! They pointed me in the right direction and I was able to get the converter working with this code:

```
binder.forField(txtIsActiveAncillary)
    .withConverter(
        text -> "Yes".equals(text) ? 1 : 0,
        number -> (number == null) ? "No" : (number == 1 ? "Yes" : "No")
    )
    .bind(SJRolesQA::getIsActiveAncillary, SJRolesQA::setIsActiveAncillary);
```

The complete code for inline editing a select item with "Yes" and "No" and returning a 1 or 0 is this:

```
Select<String> mySelect = new Select<>();
mySelect.setItems("Yes","No");
mySelect.setWidthFull();
binder.forField(mySelect)
    .withConverter(
        text -> "Yes".equals(text) ? 1 : 0,
        number -> (number == null) ? "No" : (number == 1 ? "Yes" : "No")
    )
    .bind(myClass::getIntValue, myClass::setIntValue);
isAncillaryColumn.setEditorComponent(mySelect);
```

This is for someone as lost as I was - here's how to handle more than just two items. Let's assume we are mapping 5 colors and their corresponding value is an integer. Here's how to do it:

```
private static final Map<String, Integer> colorMapping = Map.of(
    "Red", 1,
    "Blue", 2,
    "Green", 3,
    "Purple", 4,
    "Black", 5
);
```

Then in your grid setup for inline editing:

```
Binder<YourDataClass> binder = new Binder<>();

binder.forField(colorSelect)
      .withConverter(
          text -> text != null ? colorMapping.getOrDefault(text, null) : null,  // Convert from String to Integer, handle null text
          number -> {
              if (number == null) return null;
              return colorMapping.entrySet()            // Convert from Integer to String, handle null number
                                 .stream()
                                 .filter(entry -> Objects.equals(entry.getValue(), number))
                                 .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                                 .findFirst()
                                 .orElse(null);
          }
      )
      .bind(YourDataClass::getColorValue, YourDataClass::setColorValue);
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use Integer as type for your Select, like here. There are probably many other solutions too.

```
@Route("select")
public class SelectView extends Div {

    public SelectView() {
        Binder<Bean> binder = new Binder<>();
        Select<Integer> select = new Select<>();
        select.setItems(1, 0);
        select.setItemLabelGenerator(item -> item == 1 ? "True" : "False");
        binder.forField(select).bind(Bean::getTruth, Bean::setTruth);
        Bean bean = new Bean();
        bean.setTruth(1);
        binder.readBean(bean);
        add(select);
    }

    public class Bean {
        private Integer truth;

        public Integer getTruth() {
            return truth;
        }

        public void setTruth(Integer truth) {
            this.truth = truth;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome solution @Tatu - THANK YOU for taking the time to add your solution!